# Does Luke 2:32 indicate that Mary would be murdered?

Tags: luke, prophecy

> BSB Luke 2:
>
> 33The child’s father and mother marveled at what was said about him.
>   34Then Simeon blessed them and said to Mary, his mother: “This child
>   is destined to cause the falling and rising of many in Israel, and to
>   be a sign that will be spoken against, 35so that the thoughts of many
>   hearts will be revealed. **And a sword will pierce your own soul too**.”

If so, why?

If not, what does it mean that a sword would pierce her soul?

Comment: Homicide would result from a sword piercing the body, not the soul.

Comment: That sounds like the beginning of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always understood that this prophecy referred to Mary's grief at the crucifixion of her beloved son; that is, it is an indirect reference to Jesus' death.  If so, it was fulfilled when Mary (John 19:25).  Further, while Mary Magdalene was crying at the Jesus' tomb on Sunday morning, I am confident that Jesus Mother was just as grief stricken, if not more so.  It is in this sense that her soul was "pierced".  (As pointed out by Nigel J, a sword (rhomphaia - large Thracian sword) can only pierce the flesh.)  Compare 1 Tim 6:10 for a similar idea (but for different reason).

Further, this prophecy of Simeon appears to echo those of Isaiah 52:14 and 53:12 of the suffering servant and so become the earliest NT prophecy of Jesus' suffering and death.

I am unaware how Mary met her death, but tradition suggests that John, who became bishop of Ephesus adopted he as his mother and she presumably lived there.  However, I do not know if her death was natural or homocide.  I suspect the former.